# Android BLE KK version , Read characteristic status = 133 is coming ,in android M it is working fine

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing app for BLE device  for android , in both KK,and >KK versions.

I am reading 12 characteristic one by one after service discover callback,
same code is working in android M version , but in KK it is not working 
after 7th characteristic is throwing status =133

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue.

This is code for callback method: this is running in service(all ble related task is running in service ie. scanning,connect, ,write characteristic, disconnect)
I am sending response to main activity using broadcast receiver

private final BluetoothGattCallback mGatttcallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

```
    private int char_read_index1, char_read_index2;    
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            gatt.discoverServices();

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;

            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            close(gatt);
            if (mScanning == false) {
                mScanning = true;
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);



        List<BluetoothGattService> listService = getSupportedGattServices(gatt);



        if (listService.size() == 5) {
            char_read_index1=0;
            listChar = getSupportedGattCharacteristic(listService.get(2));
            lischar1 = getSupportedGattCharacteristic(listService.get(3));
            lischar2 = getSupportedGattCharacteristic(listService.get(4));
            gatt.readCharacteristic(lischar1.get(char_read_index1));


        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "service is less you can not read close gatt");
            //isConnectionStarted = false;
            if(mScanning==false){
                mScanning = true;
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                disconnect(gatt);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

            if (char_read_index1 < 4) {
                calibrationValue_map.put(characteristic.getUuid().toString(), characteristic.getValue());
                temprature_calibration_index++;
                if (char_read_index1 == 4) {
                    gatt.readCharacteristic(lischar2.get(0));
                  char_read_index2=0;
                } else {
                    gatt.readCharacteristic(lischar1.get(char_read_index1));
                }


            } else if (char_read_index2 < 8) {


                    gatt.readCharacteristic(lischar2.get(char_read_index2));
                    char_read_index2++;


            } else {
```

// after reading all charectaristic ,doing charactaristic write

```
     byte[] value = new byte[1];
    byte b = 1;
    value[0] = (byte) (b & 0xff);
    bluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue(value);
    boolean status = gatt.writeCharacteristic(listcar.get(2));  
            }

        }
    }

      @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                      BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                      int status) {

        disconnect(gatt);


    }
```

Comment: You're gonna have to show us some code

Comment: I have updated code in my question ,Please check and let me know if any other info  require..!